# ORA-00936: missing expression using prompt

Tags: sql, oracle, case, prompt

Cannot get a CASE WHEN to work in my query using a variable.

```
select field1, field2
from table
where 1=1
AND GLCC.SEGMENT2 
    (CASE
    WHEN :P_AccountType =  'B' THEN  < 40000
    WHEN :P_AccountType =  'P' THEN => 40000
    ELSE
    BETWEEN '00000' AND '99999'
    END)
```

any idea where/what I do wrong

Many thanks.

Comment: Ok Barbaros, so all I add here is in right place?

Comment: (CASE
      WHEN :P_AccountType =  'B'  THEN  SEGMENT2 <  '40000'
      WHEN :P_AccountType =  'P'  THEN  SEGMENT2 >= '40000'
      ELSE  
          SEGMENT2 BETWEEN '00000' AND '99999' 
      END)

but this results in: ORA-00905: missing keyword

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the variable is the problem, you can't build a WHERE clause with syntax like that, as far as I can see.

Also, what is the 1=1 for?

And the => should surely be the other way round.

And why are you using a numeric representation of the number in two places and a character one in the other?

Try

```
select field1, field2 from table
where (GLCC.SEGMENT2 < 40000 and :P_AccountType = 'B')
or  (GLCC.SEGMENT2 >= 40000 and :P_AccountType = 'P' )
or (GLCC.SEGMENT2 BETWEEN 0 AND 99999 and :P_AccountType not in ('B','P'))
```

or something like that (not in a position to test!)

Comment: Many many thanks. your remarks about character vs numeric is correct. I mistake from me. Your suggestion works for B, for rest I do get a time out. Why do you combine variable with segment value? My intention was depending on variable input to select range of segment2 values.

Comment: I wasn't really thinking about how the variable was used, sorry, just about the where clause. Maybe try using a subselect so the variable is only specified once. Sorry, no more time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need such a collation as below :

```
SELECT field1, field2
  FROM "table"
 WHERE  
     (CASE
      WHEN :P_AccountType =  'B' AND SEGMENT2 <  '40000' THEN  1
      WHEN :P_AccountType =  'P' AND SEGMENT2 >= '40000' THEN  1
      ELSE  
          CASE WHEN SEGMENT2 BETWEEN '00000' AND '99999' THEN  1 END 
          --> the above case line is needed when :P_AccountType is neither "B", nor "P"
      END) = 1
```

Comment: Barbaros, many thanks. query runs very fast, but outcome is always same. Tried also by making values text by adding ' around the values. As segment2 values are text and not numeric. But did not make a difference. Don't quite understand purpose of all make 1?

Comment: @Fernando you're welcome. Please share the sample data to help you better. the value `1` does not have a special meaning, you can replace all `1` with `0` or any other value like `xYZ`, the main point is to satisfy the equality.

Comment: Hi Barboros,  User can select Accountype 
A = Trial Balance Accounts 00000 - 99999
B = BS Accts 00000 -39999
P = All IS Accts 40000- 99999

This variable result in a range.

So  :P_AccountType =B Segment2 should contain all Balance sheet accounts 00000 - 39999
etc.

Because segment2 values are strings I used apostrophes unless you advise me different.

Comment: @Fernando OK, then we need to keep quotes merely. By the way, rather, you can edit the question with these details.